# Best Simple Way to Protect EXE File and run it

Tags: c#, encryption, exe

I have searched for a long time for a way to protect a EXE file from being copied.

I searched for encrypt, then decrypt and run in memory without touching the HD or decrypt encrypted EXE on HD, and still load a way that the EXE keeps encrypted on the HD, but EXE runs decrypted(of course).

I have used Packers(such as Molebox) for testing, but its not very accurate, some Users just have compability errors when trying to run the EXE Application

I have tried to do this in C#, i know that in C++ there are possibilities(from some people i heard), but i am using C# and coding language, and the only thing now i could achieve was only .NET Assembly and not PE.

Hope there is a chance of this being made.

Cumpz.

EDIT: Added Example Image
[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean by "copied"? You cannot keep people from copying files they own.

Comment: You may have to build the security inside the EXE. Like on launch you will check the user running it or the machine it is supposed to run on. if not an intended user/machine then exit. event though they have the copy of exe if not allowed users can't  execute it

Comment: The EXE is some random Win32 application, i am just pretending to protect it from being copied by some more expert user.

If i just output it to some temp file, it will be not protected of course
What i really pretend is to pack it inside other C# EXE app like, or decrypt and run.

Comment: Please check this .. if this helps you .. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory

Comment: By the code i have seen there, that only works for .NET Assembly and not some PE.
I need for any Win32 Executable.

Comment: "some Users just have compability errors" - and the more complexity you add, the more likely this is to happen - for what are presumably your paying/wanted customers; Who are thus more likely to decide that the pirated version, that's bypassed any copy protection, is a better product and more worth their while using. Unless you're in the copy protection business, either buy something off the shelf (that won't be perfect) or leave it alone - spend time focussing on making a good product that people *want* to pay for.

Comment: You have to define problem better. Currently it's too broad. I understand it what you need to make a software which takes EXE file, encrypt it and pack into another EXE, which can only be run on current PC. There are multiple ways to bind to PC: registry, hidden files, hardware hash, user credentials, etc. Regarding generating EXE file there are also multiple approaches. Easiest is to generate some EXE template (by using Assembler/C, etc) what can hold encrypted generic data and when executed - decrypt and run data. I think this is what NSIS does (its compiler is packing what you install)..

Comment: The application is not to be selled, its just to be protected to avoid DLL Hack Injection(in this case, its a game).
What i am pretending, is what a packer does, like MoleBox, BoxedApp etc but its something that MY application does, not some foreign Packer, also to be encrypted, so if it is copied, it cannot be decrypted so easilly to someone just go and launch mannualy.

Imagine this, i have 10 files, and i have the EXE, to the files to be used, whe need the EXE because its the Application itself. I dotn want the user to grab that EXE by its own and excute whenever they want, only with myap